# logout not working in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, logout

After logging in to my application, I can't able to log out

```
@SessionAttributes("email")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/logout"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        session.invalidate();

        return "home";
    }

}
```

My `home.jsp` page,

```
 <p>${email}</p>
<a href="logout">Logout</a>
```

After clicked log out button still, email variable showing...

Comment: are you hitting the method log out when you click on the Logout link? Please, can you add breakpoints, debug and check, if it is hitting the method, and still not working, check your log trace for more detailed error summary?

Comment: @robot_alien yes it is hitting log out method each time If I click logout link.  I checked my log trace also, I'm didn't see any error

Comment: is there anything in the session object of that class or is it `null`? else try  `request.getSession().invalidate();`,

Comment: @robot_alien Now it's working... Thx

Comment: great thanks for letting me know & the upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, can you check if there's anything in the `session` object of that `class` or is it null? else try `request.getSession().invalidate();`
This should work!

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/logout"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request, SessionStatus session){
    session.setComplete();
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    return "login";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/logout"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request, SessionStatus session){
    session.setComplete();
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    return "login";
}
```

Try this if you want to reset email session attribute.